# Merge queries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

As you can see down below, I got this query that gets the average of how long it takes to approve a number of certain forms. I'm filtering out by giving a date range, and the date range needs to include only business days (Mon-Fri) using the Calendar table.

```
SELECT 
fg2.form_descr AS 'form_description',

CONCAT(
    FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)))) / 24), ' days ',
    MOD(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed )))), 24), ' hours ',
    MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)))), ' minutes'
) AS 'Average Approval Time',

COUNT(user_forms.form_id) AS ' number_of_forms'

FROM

forms.user_forms,
forms.forms,
forms.form_groups fg,
forms.form_groups fg2

WHERE
    user_forms.form_id = forms.form_id
    AND forms.form_group = fg.form_group_id
    AND fg.approver_group = fg2.form_group_id
    AND viewed > submitted
    AND submitted BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'

GROUP BY 
    fg.approver_group
```

The results is something like:

```
form_description      Average Approval Time         number_of_forms

'Log In'             '1 days 2 hours 04 minutes'    '35'
'Programming'        '2 days 5 hours 22 minutes'    '100'
...and so on
```

Now, I have a table called Calendar which consists of two columns. One is date, and the other is is_holiday with no primary id and/or foreign key. The Calendar table is nothing but a list of dates that tells you if it is a holiday or not.
Example:

```
Date           is_holiday

'2014-01-01'   '0'
'2014-01-02'   '0'
'2014-01-03'   '0'
and so on...

SELECT date 
FROM calendar
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) NOT IN (1,7) 
AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'
AND is_holiday = 0
```

How can I merger these 2 queries together? I have tried using two subqueries in the FROM clause, but I can't seem to get this. And yes, I did tried looking around, but I can't see to get this right.

Comment: you mean you need to check "Viewed" date is between this condition SELECT date 
FROM calendar
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) NOT IN (1,7) 
AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'   ??

Comment: you dont need a subquery, just join the calendar table as well. [edit] or do you mean you need to only count weekday, non holiday days in the calculations in the select fields? and is it submitted, or dateSubmitted - you use both

Comment: @Manadh I think the BETWEEN clause is wrong. I need to use the calendar table to filter out those dates that are weekends and is holiday. I edited my original post on the calendar query that will return only those dates that are not on a holiday and not on a weekend. At the end, I need to use that result, which will return something like 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-05 (calendar query), so the dates will not be continuous, and I need to use those dates to grab the forms on those days. Hopefully, I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want by joining the calendar table. Something like this may do it:

```
 SELECT 
    fg2.form_descr AS 'form_description',

    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)))) / 24), ' days ',
        MOD(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed )))), 24), ' hours ',
        MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateSubmitted, viewed)))), ' minutes'
    ) AS 'Average Approval Time',

    COUNT(user_forms.form_id) AS ' number_of_forms'

    FROM

    forms.user_forms,
    forms.forms,
    forms.form_groups fg,
    forms.form_groups fg2
    forms.calendar c

    WHERE
        user_forms.form_id = forms.form_id
        AND forms.form_group = fg.form_group_id
        AND fg.approver_group = fg2.form_group_id
        AND c.`date` = date(viewed)
        AND viewed > submitted
        AND viewed BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'
        AND dayofweek(viewed) NOT IN (1,7)
        AND c.is_holiday = 0

GROUP BY 
    fg.approver_group
```

This should exclude any rows where 'viewed' falls on either a holiday or a weekend.

Unless, of course, what you want to do is exclude any days that are a holiday or a weekend from these calculations: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)` in which case its an entirely different kettle of fish.

Assuming that a form is never submitted, or viewed, on a weekend or public hoilday (big assumption), all you need to do is subtract the number of days that fall into that category, and lay between submitted and viewed. This should do that.

```
     SELECT 
            fg2.form_descr AS 'form_description',

            CONCAT(
                FLOOR(
                  HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(
                    AVG(
                      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)))) / 24) -
                      (SELECT(COUNT(*) 
                         FROM calendar 
                         WHERE `date` BETWEEN submitted AND viewed 
                           AND (DAYOFWEEK(`date`) in (1,7) 
                             OR is_holiday = 1)
                      ), ' days ',
                MOD(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed )))), 24), ' hours ',
                MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateSubmitted, viewed)))), ' minutes'
            ) AS 'Average Approval Time',
   COUNT(user_forms.form_id) AS ' number_of_forms'

        FROM

        forms.user_forms,
        forms.forms,
        forms.form_groups fg,
        forms.form_groups fg2
        forms.calendar c

        WHERE
            user_forms.form_id = forms.form_id
            AND forms.form_group = fg.form_group_id
            AND fg.approver_group = fg2.form_group_id
            AND c.`date` = date(viewed)
            AND viewed > submitted
            AND viewed BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'    
    GROUP BY 
        fg.approver_group
```

[here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c998f/12) query on some fake data showing how this theory works. it should apply to what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I made some typos as it should be submitted and not dateSubmitted, and also, in the WHERE in my original post is different. I need to grab all submitted forms and get the average approval time, and I need to use the calendar table to filter out those forms that are on a holiday and on the weekends. So, if I used my original calendar query to filter out those dates that are in the weekends and holiday, how do I apply that query, which will return something like 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-05...to the first query? I don't think I can use a BETWEEN clause with that result.

Comment: i'm mildly confused. the second query i have there gets the difference in days from between submitted and viewed, and then subtracts a number of days equal to the number of weekend and holiday days in the same period. is that not what you want?

Comment: @FNMT8L9IN82 i added a fiddle link to the answer to demonstrate - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c998f/11

Comment: @FNMT8L9IN82 by 'filter out the forms that are on a holiday or weekend' do you mean forms with a `submitted` or `viewed` date that falls on a holiday or weekend, or simply do not count the days that occur BETWEEN `submitted` and `viewed` that are hoildays or weekends?

Comment: Both you and DACrosby stir me in the right directions, but your was the right one. Thanks!!!! Unfortunately, I cannot give you a vote up since I do not have enough credit. Once I get enough, I will come back here and give you my vote up.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, But should work. I'm using `[ ... ]` to shorten the code down to just the new pieces - leave your original query as-is.

```
SELECT
    [ ... ],
    is_holiday

FROM
    [ ... ],
    calendar ON calendar.Date = viewed

WHERE
    [ ... ]
    AND calendar.Date = viewed

GROUP BY
    [ ... ]
```

Essentially you're just joining the `calendar` table where the dates match and grabbing the corresponding `is_holiday` field.

If you're looking specifically for holidays use `AND calendar.Date <> '0'` (or use `AND calendar.Date = '0'` if you want non-holidays) after `calendar.Date = viewed`

Also, you don't need the lookup table to figure if the date is a weekend - it's the same date as in the first table.

```
DAYOFWEEK(viewed) NOT IN (1,7)
```

**Edit**

Here it is altogether.

```
SELECT 
fg2.form_descr AS 'form_description',

CONCAT(
    FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)))) / 24), ' days ',
    MOD(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed )))), 24), ' hours ',
    MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, submitted, viewed)))), ' minutes'
) AS 'Average Approval Time',

COUNT(user_forms.form_id) AS ' number_of_forms',
is_holiday

FROM

forms.user_forms,
forms.forms,
forms.form_groups fg,
forms.form_groups fg2,
calendar ON calendar.Date = viewed

WHERE
    user_forms.form_id = forms.form_id
    AND forms.form_group = fg.form_group_id
    AND fg.approver_group = fg2.form_group_id
    AND viewed > submitted
    AND submitted BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'
    AND calendar.Date = viewed
    AND is_holiday = '0'
    AND DAYOFWEEK(calendar.Date) NOT IN (1,7)

GROUP BY 
    fg.approver_group
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my post as I forgot to add a couple of pieces and typos. I need to grab all submitted forms and get the average approval time, and I need to use the calendar table to filter out those forms that are on a holiday and on the weekends. How do I use this SQL: SELECT date FROM calendar WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) NOT IN (1,7) 
AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'
AND is_holiday = 0 and use this "date range" and apply it to the first query? This query will return something like 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-05, so the dates will not be continuous.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. Essentially, you'll cut out the second query entirely - I've added it into the first query. The query (see Edit above), gets all of the data from the first and second queries; it returns the averages but only where the `Calendar.Date` is not a weekend or holiday.

Comment: If you can, I'd recommend changing the `Date` column name to something like `valid_dates`.or `holiday_date`  ["Date" is a MySQL function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) so it gets a bit confusing to use the sme wording. Also, you may consider modifying your calendar table to only include holidays (sounds like it presently includes every date?) - then just check that the date isn't in that table.

Comment: Both you and _pala stir me in the right direction. Once I get enough credit, I will give you a vote up!